# How to determine quantity and names of public views in lists / libraries

Tags: list, list-view

I'd like to query a list or library to determine how many public views it contains and what the name of those views are. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this small powershell script for this:

```
[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = Get-SPSite "http://yoursharepointsiteurl/"
$web = $site.rootweb
$list = $web.Lists["yourlistname"]
Write-host $list.Views
```

It will show the publicly available list views for a given list.

Comment: Thanks Arko. I called the PowerShell via C# and attached it as a WebPart to get the result on the list view I needed. I was originally hoping to find a simpler way via CAML.